# Gaining badges retroactively

Tags: feature-request

I suggest to add this feature of retroactively gaining badges.
Badges that gained based on quantity of visits/answer upvotes etc shouldn't be relied on tracking.
For example, say I'm a somewhat new user, and my answer got upvoted while I was tracking the "Informed" badge.
I will not receive the "Supporter" badge even though I have at least one answer getting upvoted because I didn't track it; After getting the "Informed" badge and having answers being upvoted, I will not get the "Supporter" badge retroactively even if I then track it, only when one of my answers will get upvoted again.
Not cool guys.

Let us gain badges fairly, even retroactively.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Tracking badges has absolutely no effect on whether you get them or not. It's only a trick to let you see your progress, you'll get the badge whether you track it or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is founded on a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't how badges work at all, so I think you're confused about something. I never pay attention to the badge tracking feature and I get badges all the time; all tracking does is let you monitor your progress towards a particular badge if you're particularly interested in it. As for "retroactively" gaining badges, that word doesn't seem to apply to what you're talking about, but you *can* get badges retroactively if they are added to the site and you already qualified for them

Comment: I don't think we can get badges retroactively - if we did, way more people would have that edit+answer badge (Illuminator?). Or perhaps an exception was made for it.

Comment: @muru Illuminator is a good example, since it was added [September 30, 2014](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/239898/6) and [slm immediately earned it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/233/illuminator); I suspect he didn't edit/answer 500 questions that same day

Comment: @muru - there were several occurrences over the years where badges were introduced and myself and others instantly got them b/c we'd already met all the requirements and I literally did nothing "new" to get them.